# With $(AB^{-1})^T$, what comes first, the multiplication or the transpose?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, transpose

In part of the question we have $(AB^{-1})^T$.

My first thought was that I multiply $A$ and $B^{-1}$, then apply the transpose.

But according to theory $(AB)^T = (B)^T(A)^T,$ so this says I should get the transpose first, then multiply.

I'm confused about either sticking to the theory or what I did was right.

Comment: Either way would be right, they’re the same.

Comment: A seemingly common misunderstanding when learning identities (like $(AB)^T=B^TA^T$) is that you *must* use them.  All it's giving you is a manipulation that you *can* do.  Don't confuse "is" with "ought"!  (Knowing them can save you a whole lot of work, like say in calculating $B^T(AB^{-1})^T$.  But it's just that you *can* save work.  No one says you must!  It can be good trying things in multiple ways to make sure you didn't make a mistake, though.)

Comment: @KyleMiller but I got two different answers and its a true or false question so using it is giving me false and not using it is giving me true

Comment: If you use an identity and get two different answers, then at least one of three things must be true: (1) you did the first calculation wrong, (2) you did the second calculation wrong, or (3) the identity is wrong.  This identity is not wrong, so that leaves (1) or (2).

Comment: @sarah23 you should show us what you did, or use a computer software to verify your calculations - I suggest Symbolab for having visual matrices you can enter elements into, but WolframAlpha is the typical choice for this sort of thing

Comment: @FShrike yup you're right I re-calculated the whole thing and my calculation had an extra negative sign, thank you for the help

Answer (score 2):

The order is unimportant from a principles standpoint, but in some situations one formula may be more useful than the other. The identity $(AB)^T=B^TA^T$ is an algebraic tool to prove theorems and solve equations, it isn’t necessarily a computational tool. $(B^{-1})^TA^T=(AB^{-1})^T$, calculate whichever feels more natural (I’d go for the RHS myself).

Comment: but I'm getting different answers that's why I'm confused

Comment: Show us what you did @sarah23

Comment: and was what you did respectful of the fact that matrix multiplication isn’t in general commutative? $AB^{-1}\neq B^{-1}A$ in general